# Understanding == operator for Object Comparison in Java

Tags: java

I understand that == operator checks for equal references(addresses) but I am not getting how the compiler is throwing below error when comparing `Thread` and `String` object.

`java: incomparable types: java.lang.Thread and java.lang.String`

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread();
    Object o = new Object();
    String s = new String("");

    System.out.println(t == o);//no issues here

    System.out.println(t==s);// but this throws above error
  }
```

Why is it allowing comparison between `Thread` and `Object` but not `Thread` and `String`?

Comment: Because `Thread` extends `Object`, therefore, `o` could secretly be a `Thread`. However, `String` isn't a subclass of `Thread`  (or vice versa) so there's no way they could possibly be equal

Comment: The compiler is being helpful by detecting a programming error at compile time. If you want to make the compilation error go away, you can cast one of the operands to an Object, like `(Object) t == s`. Of course, this is totally useless since the expression will always evaluate to false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is specified that comparing reference types which cannot be converted between them must result in a compile error. See the [JLS chapter 15.21.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> ### 15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=
>
> [...]
>
> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).

Answer (score 11):

Although it has been answered beautifully by @Progman, I want to put it in another perspective.

`Thread extends Object` , Hence it is valid to say `Object o = new Thread()`
Now `String extends Object` , but `String` does not extends `Thread` hence `String iDoNotComplie = new Thread()` is not valid.

Now If we have `Thread t = new Thread()` then If we have a reference of type `Object` , `o`  and another reference of type `String`, `s` then it may be that `o` is actually referring to an object of `Thread` but it is impossible for `s` to ever refer to an object of `Thread`. This makes `o==s` work and `o==t` also work but `s==t` doesn't work, as it simply fails to compile.

Comment: Upvote for also explaining why they can't be converted to one another

Answer (score 0):

Simply, this is happening because an `Object` can be anything. It is changeable and can be assigned to multiple things. As explained by @nits.kk, Since `Thread extends Object` and `String extends Object`. It makes it possible to use `t == o` and `s == o` since they are both considered as an `Object`. However, `string` is very different from `thread` even though they are both objects, they are not in the same category. Hence, they cannot be compared and it will throw a compile error as explained by @Progman.